# How to correctly use text overflow in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to hide the overflow text of `li` and my `li` looks like this

```
<li class="food_item">
   <a href="#" class="food_name" title="test">
       testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
   </a>
   <span>(12)</span>
</li>
<li class="food_item">
   <a href="#" class = "food_name">a short one</a>
   <span>(12)</span>
</li>
```

and my css

```
.food_category>.food_item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.food_category .food_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`food_category` is the class name of the `ul` tag, now the effect is below:[image]

the `span` and the `a` tag are not  in the same line, I assume it's about the `inline-block` property of the `a`, but if I remove that, the `text-overflow` will not work and the overflow text will not be hidden. I'm stuck here, can anybody help me? how can I make the `a` and `span` show in the same line while keeping overflow text hidden?

**Update**
this is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/842Rc/2/), btw,I didn't set the `css` of `span`. What I want is to make the `span` text right behind the `a` tag like this `testest... (12)`.Thx!

Comment: [fiddle pls](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please recreate this in JSFiddle. You also didn't include the css you have on the `span`

Comment: @richard I've updated your fiddle to include a fix for the alignment issue. See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your update, you need to set the anchor tag and span tag to be vertically aligned at the top of the list element. Add the following to your CSS:

```
.food_item a,
.food_item span {
    vertical-align: top;    
}
```

This produces the desired behavior.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/842Rc/6/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still cannot make the span close to the `a` text, in your way, it looks more like a table.

Comment: What exactly do you mean close to the `a`? You can reduce the space between the `a` and `span` by applying a `margin-left: -10px;` to the `span`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: but the length of the `a` is different, What I expect is there is one or some fixed blanks between `a` and `span`, I can't just add `-10px`, it may overlay the text

Comment: @richard The length of the `<a>` tags are not different. The text inside may be different but the `<a>` tags are 60% of each `.food_item` which is 25% of the page width. It's a responsive width, but nonetheless it's fixed. Every `<a>` tag will be the same size. The content inside the `<a>`'s may differ however.

Comment: Sorry but it's a little unclear as to what you are wanting to achieve?

Comment: my mistake, then what I want is to adjust the width of `a`, I hope the a tag can be shorten to the length of its text and then make the `span ` close to it

Comment: @richard That's tricky because for `text-overflow` to work, I believe you have to specify a `width`. Not sure there's any way around that short of dynamic calculations via JS

Comment: what about not use `text-overflow`? is there any other way to hide the overflow text and meet my need?

Comment: @richard That depends. What would be your measurement of overflow? You'd have to decide a threshold and implement a dynamic JS solution.

Comment: the range should be 0 and 25%,I'll think about it

Comment: @richard Maybe `max-width: 60%` on the anchor tag would work. That way it could grow up to your current setting of 60%, but it could be smaller. If it hits the max threshold, `text-overflow` should kick in providing the desired ellipsis. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/842Rc/7/). I think it does what you're looking for.

Comment: *Plus* a demo. Gotta luv 'em ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
.food_item span {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

and add `float:left;` to `.food_item .food_name`

```
.food_item .food_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/842Rc/4/)

You may need to update the margin/padding for the spacing of the `span`.

I would also recommend adding something like `clearfix` on each `li` element to prevent float issues:

```
<li class="food_item clearfix">
   ...
</li>
<li class="food_item clearfix">
   ...
</li>

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: for the space between the span and a, I'm not sure how to update it, should I calculate it for every span and update it? or is there a better way?